# R markdown knit issue

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I was trying to use Rmarkdown fro the first time to generate a pdf and got error messages.

I tried to download texlive from here http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html 
" install-tl-unx.tar.gz (4mb) "  but i don't quite get the instruction to install and not sure if it is the right solution for my issue.

Error I got:

> ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `http://www.compbio.dundee.ac.uk/user/pschofie
>   ld/Projects/teaching_pg//figures/openmarkdown.png' not found: using draft setti
>   ng.
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile RNA-seq-Analysis-1---Introduction-to-R,-RStudio-and-Rmarkdown-.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See RNA-seq-Analysis-1---Introduction-to-R,-RStudio-and-Rmarkdown-.log for more info.
>   Execution halted
>
> No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform: https://www.latex-project.org/get/
>
> If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R: tinytex::install_tinytex()
>
> Otherwise consider MiKTeX on Windows - http://miktex.org
>
> MacTeX on macOS - https://tug.org/mactex/
>     (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome *strongly* recommended)
>
> Linux: Use system package manager

Comment: Try to download in your R console: `install.packages("tinytex")` and then `tinytex::install_tinytex()`. After a successful installation try to knit your file again.

Comment: @J_F YES I did that and it gave me the same error..